Geometrically, why can every cubic be depressed?
I understand how the algebraic process of depressing a cubic works: given a general cubic polynomial $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$, we make a substitution $x = t + \frac{-b}{3a}$ to eliminate the quadratic term, simplifying it to a "depressed" cubic of the form $p(t) = pt^3 + qt + r$. I also understand that what this "means" is that we are recentering the graph so that the inflection point is on the Y-axis. What I'm struggling with is whether there’s a geometric interpretation of this process.
While experimenting with graphs on Desmos, I noticed that, near the origin, cubic polynomials tend to behave similarly to quadratics, suggesting that there could be some geometric reason why a shift in the variable makes the quadratic term disappear. But I can't seem to wrap my head around why we should expect such a substitution to exist, geometrically and how this shift "aligns" the curve to eliminate the quadratic component.
Is there an intuitive way to see why this works geometrically, beyond the algebra? Specifically, what does depressing the cubic do to the shape of the graph, and how can we interpret the absence of the quadratic term visually?
EDIT: In other words, why does recentering the graph so that the inflection point is on the y-axis coorespond to eliminating the quadratic term?

If you are in a field of characteristic $3$ then you can't depress a cubic. For instance, over a field of characteristic not equal to $2$ and $3$, then you can write any elliptic curve in the short Weierstrass form $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$. But over a field of characteristic $3$, you may have to write an $x^2$ term.

@daruma - I am only talking about polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$

It seems to me that your description in the first paragraph is a geometric explanation

Also, for a depressed cubic the sum of its zeros (include the complex ones) is equal to zero. This follows from Vieta relations. Obviously the same applies to the average of the zeros.

@MPW But why does recentering the graph so that the inflection point is on the y-axis coorespond to eliminating the quadratic term

@MicahZarin: What happens when you take the second derivative of a depressed cubic?

This answer does not require the notion of derivatives to be understood.
By sake of simplicity, consider a cubic polynomial $f(x)$ whose constant term is $0$. Otherwise consider the polynomial $f(x)-f(0)$.
If the term of degree 2 is also zero, then the polynomial is an odd function (i. e. $f(-x)=-f(x)$).
Geometrically it means that its graph is symmetric to the origin $O(0,0)$. Since the graph of any cubic is always symmetric to its inflection point, it means that the inflection point is on the origin.

But then you need to show the graph of a cubic has a 180 degree symmetry about an inflection point.

@VivaanDaga You can show this with tracing paper and a pin. (Or, of course, algebraically in the obvious fashion.)

You seem to be asking why recentering the graph so that the inflection point is on the $y$-axis eliminates the $x^2$ term.
Note that if the inflection point was on the $y$-axis then the second derivative must be $0$ at $x=0.$ But this is only possible if there is no $x^2$ term.
This explains geometrically why every cubic can be depressed: every cubic can be shifted so that its inflection point is on the $y$-axis, but by the argument above that amounts to depressing the cubic.

This method also works for quartic equations to an extent. Shifting a quartic by an amount to make the vertex of the double derivative parabola on the y-axis kills the quadratic term.
